# Which horses to bet on, given known probability of winning

Tags: gambling

Say that I have calculated a probability of winning for every single horse in a collection of races (say, all the races on one day). The odds being offered by the bookmaker can be converted into an implied probability of winning. So (assuming that my probability of winning calculations are better than the bookmaker's) I could bet on a horse so long as:

my Pwin > bookie's implied Pwin

(this could be true for more than one horse per race)

But given a maximum budget for placing my bets, how would I distribute my bets amongst all the horses in all the races in order to get the highest expected return? I realise that this question may be a bit broad for a complete answer here, but I dare say that it's a well analysed problem, so just knowing where to look would be very helpful.

FYI: The relationship between implied probability of winning and the [decimal odds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odds#Decimal_odds) offered by the bookie is:

Pwin = 1 / decimal odds

Comment: I have no experience with betting, but why does bookie's implied Pwin bothers you in this case?

Comment: If the bookmaker thinks the horse is more likely to win than you do, then the odds will be poor value. Say you correctly worked out that a horse has a 20% chance of winning but the bookmaker incorrectly thinks it has a 50% chance of winning then betting on this horse will result in a 20% chance of doubling your money and 80% chance of losing it all.... not good.

Comment: But what you think and what bookmaker thinks does not have anything to do with what horse will actually win... I'm afraid you'd need to add some more details (by editing your question) about what actually happens in such betting so we understand each other better.

Comment: See edit to question... So if the (decimal) odds being offered by the bookie are 4.0 then it implies that the bookie thinks the horse has a 25% chance of winning.

Comment: What's your goal?  If it's just to maximize your expected gains, then it seems you should go all-in on the most profitable bet.

Comment: For us to suggest something more "suitable" than working on the basis of expected gains we'd have to have some idea of your utility function for risky returns. If you have a large bankroll (much larger than your bets) you might work on an expected return basis but otherwise that probably won't make sense.

Comment: I suspect highest expected return is what I'm after (question edited accordingly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you are trying to maximize your expected profit, you don't really care about the bookie's implied chance of winning.  Assuming your $Pwin$ is correct, you only care about that and your winnings (or losses). So,
$$E[profit] = \sum_{Race \in Races} (Pwin_{Race}*Bet_{Race}*(Odds_{Race}-1) - (1-Pwin_{Race}) * Bet_{Race}) \\
= \sum_{Race \in Races} Bet_{Race} (Pwin_{Race}*Odds_{Race} - Pwin_{Race} + Pwin_{Race} - 1 ) \\
= \sum_{Race \in Races} Bet_{Race} (Pwin_{Race}*Odds_{Race} - 1)$$
Note that if $Pwin_{Race}*Odds_{Race} = 1$, then your expected profit is 0.

Now, if we assume the same bet for any race, then you want to choose races that maximize $$Bet*\sum_{Race \in Races} (Pwin_{Race}*Odds_{Race} - 1 ) \\ = -Bet*n_{bets}+Bet*\sum_{Race \in Races} Pwin_{Race}*Odds_{Race})$$
where $n_{bets}$ is the number of races where you place a bet.

Comment: Just noticed on the top line Odds should be replaced by (Odds-1). Odds is what you get back from the bookie if you win, but (Odds-1) will be your profit. You will need to change other things accordingly.